# Paypal Chained Adaptive Payments - Is It Still Viable?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I currently use Paypal Chained Adaptive Payments on my website to split payments between merchants. Currently, we are undergoing a rewrite during which time I went back to read some of the documentation on Adaptive Payments.

I noticed this message below which gives me the vibe that Adaptive Payments may be phased out/discontinued in the future.

Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal.

Is this case? Should I be looking for a new payment solution?

Comment: Hi Tango - That's correct. This product has been sunset-ed, however if your working with a client that has an account manager may be able to get that turned on. That said, the alternative method would be PayPal's marketplace. Take note though as there is an approval process as well.

Comment: Ok so at some point in time Adaptive Payments will simply cease to work is that correct? Currently its still working on my website. I will look into the Marketplace. Do you know if it supports chained payments?

Comment: No, they will not stop working these payment feature. See below comment. Also, you may want to check the MarketPlace functions on what APIs are allowed. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this true. PayPal has finally decided to take this off from its available product since January 2017. The option left is by using their new product called Marketplace. This however required a permission to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I will look into Marketplace. I presume at some point in time Adaptive payments will simply stop working? At this moment it is still functional on my site

Comment: no. The method has allowed grandfathering, therefore if the client is already approved for it, they will not remove it from their profile as there are large enterprise merchants using it

Comment: thanks! i have submitted application to be considered for the Marketplace, hopefully it works out since I'm already a long time user of Adaptive payments